# Origin of "Caught between a rock and a hard place"

Tags: meaning, etymology

> caught between a rock and a hard place

Where is this expression coming from? I understood the meaning but, for me, literal translation doesn't make sense. Can you give me some image?

Comment: The *first* search result I got when searching for "caught between a rock and a hard place" was "Idiom: Between a rock and a hard place: *If you are caught between a rock and a hard place, you are in a position where you have to choose between unpleasant alternatives, and your choice might cause you problems; you will not be able to satisfy everyone.*" at http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/between+a+rock+and+a+hard+place.html.  We expect people asking questions to have done at least some basic research themselves before posting questions here: we are not a search engine for you!

Comment: @TrevorD, Hide is not asking about the meaning, but about the origin.

Comment: OK - but he still shows no research! And the 5th result in my search was http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32785/expression-caught-between-a-rock-and-a-hard-place - so I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: I suspect that the origin may actually go back to the case of a wood-wheeled wagon where the wheel has fallen down into a depression along side a rock.  This analogy would have been familiar to folks 100 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I have no evidence for this, but I think the point is that a ***rock*** is a ***hard place***. So it's like

> six of one and half a dozen of the other,

but in a negative sense.

Comment: +1 *Hard place* is a euphemism for *rock* and the phrase is a bit wry.

Answer (score -1):

Just imagine that you have a huge rock on one side and a brick wall on the other. WHichever direction you go in you'll hit something which causes you pain. That's the best literal transalation I can give. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

It means a dilemma in which you have two choices to proceed, neither of them being favorable in the circumstances given.

To give you an Image:

[image]